# Pandas, select a single column where a second column has a NaN value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    a   b   c
0   Alabama[edit]   NaN NaN
1   Auburn  (Auburn University)[1]
2   Florence    (University of
3   Jacksonville    (Jacksonville   State
4   Livingston  (University of
```

I'd like to add a column to the dataframe called 'State' that copies the value of column 'a' when column 'b' has a NaN value, otherwise it will just place a NaN value in the state column.

I have tried:

```
df['State'] = np.where(df['b'] == np.NaN, df['a'], np.NaN)
df['State'] = df.loc[df['b'] == np.NaN, 'a']
```

However for some reason both of these do not seem to evaluate the np.NaN. If i modify the criteria to == '(Auburn' then it finds the row and correctly copies the value of column 'a' into 'State'

If i use this function:
`df1 = df[df['b'].isnull()]` then i get all the relevant rows but in a new dataframe which i was trying to avoid.

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks
JP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your mistake is in your belief that `df['b'] == np.NaN` selects NaNs... it does not, as this example shows:

```
In [1]: np.nan == np.nan
Out[1]: False
```

This is the mathematical definition of NaN. Since NaN != NaN, doing an equality comparison on NaN just won't cut it. Use `isna` or `isnull` or `np.isnan`, these functions are meant for this very purpose.

For example,

```
df['State'] = np.where(df['b'].isnull(), df['a'], np.NaN)
```

Or,

```
df['State'] = df.loc[df['b'].isnull(), 'a']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using `isnull` with `where`,Since NaN has the property that it doesn't equal itself

```
df.a.where(df['b'].isnull())
Out[112]: 
0    Alabama[edit]
1              NaN
2              NaN
3              NaN
4              NaN
Name: a, dtype: object
```